# Azure Devops Require Build Success before Pull Request can be completed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branch, build-definition, policies

I would like to enforce a policy on my Pull Requests in Azure Devops (using Azure Repositories) to only allow a PR to be complete IFF the build definition succeeds. Based on this documenation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops and what I have tested so far the builds only trigger after the PR is marked complete. So in the event that a build failure occurs, the broken code makes it into the master (or target branch). I'd like to disable the ability to complete a PR until the Build Succeeds. This was possible in Team Foundation Server but I have not been able to set this up in Azure Devops.

I have reviewed the Branch Policies section and it is clear how to require a review/approval from a member of a specific group prior to allowing the PR to be marked Complete. So the hooks seem to exist, however, I have only been able to trigger a build definition AFTER the build is marked Complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Require a certain build to run with your PR

The "[Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation)" section of the link you mentioned does exactly what you describe.

1. Go to the branch policies **of the master(target) branch**
2. Select the build you want to enforce and select "required"

> Set a policy requiring changes in a pull request to build successfully with the protected branch before the pull request can be completed.

edit: this is how it looks like afterwards:
[image]

### Require a certain user to review/approve

Look at the section "[automatically include code reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#automatically-include-code-reviewers)".

> If you select Required next to a path entry, then the pull request cannot be completed until:
>
> - Every user added as a reviewer for the path approves the changes.
> - At least one person in every group added to the path approves the changes.

Comment: I  agree, the documentation claims it does what I am looking for, but the behavior doesn't support it. I have a build setup in my master branch policy. I have it set to "required" and "automatic". However, this build runs AFTER the PR is completed. In my test case I introduce build errors in a PR and "Complete" it.  
1) The Build runs/fails 
2) Introduces the broken code into the master branch
I would like the build to trigger "OnCreationOfNewPR" or some similar event...against the master and for it to disable the ability to press "Complete" until the build succeeds. Is that possible?

Comment: I just added a picture from how it looks like. I can't complete the PR because the build failed. Taken right our of our project. I would suggest you try creating a new repository and just enable multiple policies to get a feel for it. Be aware that existing pull requests don't always update right away when you change the policies. If nothing works, create a bug report.

Comment: Thank you Alex AIT, I tested in another repo and saw it all working..turns out my filter path was causing an issue here.

Comment: Yes, the filter paths can be very tricky to get right :-/ Glad I could help!